# Ordering object values in a binary search tree

Tags: c++, sorting, binary-search-tree

I'm inserting the following items into a binary search tree:

```
Mayweather,Floyd,1,105,105,0,Boxing
Ronaldo,Cristiano,2,80,52,28,Soccer
James,LeBron,3,72.3,19.3,53,Basketball
Messi,Lionel,4,64.7,41.7,23,Soccer
Bryant,Kobe,5,61.5,30.5,31,Basketball
Woods,Tiger,6,61.2,6.2,55,Golf
Federer,Roger,7,56.2,4.2,52,Tennis
Mickelson,Phil,8,53.2,5.2,48,Golf
Nadal,Rafael,9,44.5,14.5,30,Tennis
Ryan,Matt,10,43.8,42,1.8,Football
Pacquiao,Manny,11,41.8,41,0.8,Boxing
Ibrahimovic,Zlatan,12,40.4,36.4,4,Soccer
Rose,Derrick,13,36.6,17.6,19,Basketball
Bale,Gareth,14,36.4,25.4,11,Soccer
Falcao,Radamel,15,36.4,32.4,3,Soccer
```

Where rank is the first integer in the csv.  And as you can see, most are already in order, but not once they are in the binary search tree and if I do a pre, post, or inorder traversal they are also out of order.

I've tried numerous ways, but assuming one cannot use an array, vector, or any other object - just the tree, how can this be done?

```
void displayRank(Athlete& anItem)
{
        cout << "Player: " << anItem.getRank() << endl;
}

void AthleteDatabase::displayByRank(void)
{
    athleteDatabaseBST.preorderTraverse(displayRank);
}
```

The built in traversals print rank in a random order because last name is the key.  Any helps is greatly appreciated!

Below is the BinarySearchTree.h file:

```
class BinarySearchTree : public BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>
{
private:
   BinaryNode<ItemType>* rootPtr;

protected:
   //------------------------------------------------------------
   // Protected Utility Methods Section:
   // Recursive helper methods for the public methods.
   //------------------------------------------------------------
   // Recursively finds where the given node should be placed and
   // inserts it in a leaf at that point.
   BinaryNode<ItemType>* insertInorder(BinaryNode<ItemType>* subTreePtr,
                                       BinaryNode<ItemType>* newNode);

   // Removes the given target value from the tree while maintaining a
   // binary search tree.
   BinaryNode<ItemType>* removeValue(BinaryNode<ItemType>* subTreePtr,
                                     const ItemType target,
                                     bool& success);

   // Removes a given node from a tree while maintaining a
   // binary search tree.
   BinaryNode<ItemType>* removeNode(BinaryNode<ItemType>* nodePtr);

   // Removes the leftmost node in the left subtree of the node
   // pointed to by nodePtr.
   // Sets inorderSuccessor to the value in this node.
   // Returns a pointer to the revised subtree.
   BinaryNode<ItemType>* removeLeftmostNode(BinaryNode<ItemType>* subTreePtr,
                                            ItemType& inorderSuccessor);

   // Returns a pointer to the node containing the given value,
   // or nullptr if not found.
   BinaryNode<ItemType>* findNode(BinaryNode<ItemType>* treePtr,
                                  const ItemType& target) const;

public:
   //------------------------------------------------------------
   // Constructor and Destructor Section.
   //------------------------------------------------------------
   BinarySearchTree();
   BinarySearchTree(const ItemType& rootItem);
   BinarySearchTree(const BinarySearchTree<ItemType>& tree);
   virtual ~BinarySearchTree();

   //------------------------------------------------------------
   // Public Methods Section.
   //------------------------------------------------------------
   bool isEmpty() const;
   int getHeight() const;
   int getNumberOfNodes() const;
   ItemType getRootData() const throw(PrecondViolatedExcep);
   void setRootData(const ItemType& newData) const throw(PrecondViolatedExcep);
   bool add(const ItemType& newEntry);
   bool remove(const ItemType& anEntry);
   void clear();
   ItemType getEntry(const ItemType& anEntry) const throw(NotFoundException);
   bool contains(const ItemType& anEntry) const;

   //------------------------------------------------------------
   // Public Traversals Section.
   //------------------------------------------------------------
   void preorderTraverse(void visit(ItemType&)) const;
   void inorderTraverse(void visit(ItemType&)) const;
   void postorderTraverse(void visit(ItemType&)) const;

   //------------------------------------------------------------
   // Overloaded Operator Section.
   //------------------------------------------------------------
   BinarySearchTree<ItemType>& operator=(const BinarySearchTree<ItemType>& rightHandSide);   
}; // end BinarySearchTree
```

Comment: The tree's structure is defined by the key. If you want to traverse in rank order, use the rank as key.

Comment: @molbdnilo I agree, but how do I do this other than modifying the file?

Comment: There should be no reason to modify the input, if the implementation is sensible. The details would depend on your tree implementation, about which we know nothing.

Comment: @molbdnilo fair enough.  I'll add some details to see if you can help further. I'm just totally lost on how to do this.

Comment: Your insert method installs the records in order of the some key, in this case the 'rank'.  pre/in/post order traverse only makes sense in the context of a sorted tree.  The tree remains sorted on the insert choice.  With 15 entries, and rank from 1..15, the top and middle of the tree will be 7.  So in-order traverse is the only one to be 'in-order'.  pre and post traverse will not.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN, sorry I'm still new to binary search trees.  So the key my tree is being sorted on is the lastName.  When I do an inorder traverse on the tree it prints the lastNames in alphabetical order. I don't know how to get it to sort based on the rank.

Comment: @inquisitor - Last name sounds fine  to me, and more typical usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you cannot dump the contents of your tree into a vector and sort the vector on different fields, I suppose you could try the following:

step 1: find, report, and keep a copy of the smallest element based on the new sort field.  (search the entire tree)

step 2 (and subsequent): find, report, and keep copy of the smallest element that is also larger than the previous smallest element. (search entire tree)

Not terribly efficient, but I think you should be able to make this work.

Good luck.

Comment: @inquisitor - you have to handle multiple minimums.  So I suggest you split both step's:    1a. - find the minimum (search entire tree), 1b. - report each node that matches this minimum (search entire tree),  and similar 2 pass for step 2.